how to deal with the dotfiles of email account in chezmoi
I try to use chezmoi to transfer my dotfiles to another linux computer. I see how I can deal with  the "normal", text based configurations. What I do not undertand is how to deal with e.g. the .thunderbird directory? It is important, in my case, to transfer the non-trivial account descriptions using chezmoi, but obviously I do not want to put the current state of maildirs into it.
I have the impression that the problem is essentially the same for thunderbird, evolution, kmail or any other GUI based email client. Has any of them a better separation of the configuration (accounts etc.) and the current email content? Such a separation would make the task of chezmoi easier?
I would like to hear of any example how to use chezmoi with a GUI email client.
